# Mensagens de fechamento e bloqueio de comentários de uma pergunta mostram informações contraditórias quanto a poder receber novas respostas

Tags: bug

Quando uma pergunta é fechada, não são mais aceitas respostas. E quando ela está somente com os comentários [bloqueados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts), ela ainda pode receber respostas.

Mas quando uma pergunta está ao mesmo tempo fechada **e** com os comentários bloqueados, ela não pode receber novas respostas. Porém, as mensagens que aparecem neste caso são contraditórias. Veja um exemplo:

[image: mensagens de fechamento e bloqueio de comentários]

Repare que a mensagem de fechamento diz - corretamente - que não são aceitas novas respostas. Mas a mensagem do bloqueio de comentários diz - erroneamente - que ainda são aceitas novas respostas.

Entendo que a mensagem de bloqueio ("*ainda são aceitos novas respostas etc...*") estaria correta somente se a pergunta não estivesse fechada. Mas se ela está fechada - e portanto não aceita mais respostas - a mensagem do bloqueio não deveria refletir esta situação?

Talvez devesse ser algo como:

> Os comentários nessa pergunta foram desativados, e como ela está fechada, não são aceitas novas respostas.

Ou:

> Os comentários nessa pergunta foram desativados.

<sup>E não precisaria de mais nada, pois a mensagem de fechamento já indica que não são aceitas novas respostas.</sup>

Ou qualquer outra opção, desde que esteja de acordo com o status atual da pergunta (de não poder receber respostas, caso esteja fechada).

E talvez a mensagem do bloqueio devesse ser dinâmica: se a pergunta está fechada, não diga que respostas são aceitas (só diga isso se ela estiver aberta).

Obs: sei que a própria interface do site não mostra mais o campo de respostas quando a pergunta está fechada, mas de qualquer forma as mensagens contraditórias podem acabar confundindo os usuários (principalmente os menos familiarizados com o funcionamento do site <sup><sub>*e que infelizmente são maioria*</sub></sup>).

---

<sup>*Não coloquei o link da pergunta porque daqui a 7 dias o bloqueio sumirá, então o link se tornará irrelevante.*</sup>

Comment: Ótima iniciativa +1. Ainda sim devo dizer que apesar de parecer um conflito de ideias se olharmos de outro ponto de vista na verdade "tecnicamente" são quase aceitas respostas novas, porque muitos fechamentos tem chance de reabertura, falta só um pouco de empenho por parte dos próprios APs, então mesmo que o fechamento impossibilite isso, se a pergunta voltar a ser reaberta o lock permanece, porque são ações diferentes e usadas por motivos diferentes. No caso tenho usado muito isso para direcionar usuários novos sobre o uso da edição

Comment: a edição para novos usuários é algo confuso de compreender, porque o proprio fechamento é confuso para elas, então muitos pensam que devem explicar a pergunta nos comentários e volta e meia (menos comum) também reclamam do fechamento e querem debater que deveria ser reaberta, quando o foco disso deveria ser no META. Muitos também não entendem e nem sabem que existe uma fila de analise para reabertura, então minha proposta é tirar as ferramentas que causam mais confusão temporariamente e focar novos usuários no uso da edição.

Comment: para quem não sabe ao editar uma pergunta fechada ela é levada para fila de analises, ou seja, lá terá 5 usuários para avaliar a edição e a pergunta se bem editada provavelmente será reaberta, ou seja, ao usarem os comentários e não entenderem o editar elas podem perder oportunidades de terem a pergunta reaberta mais cedo, o que tomará na verdade um tempo desnecessário. Então assim que passar pelo processo e for reaberta, os comentários podem até continuar bloqueados (algo que sempre olho, pois sempre revejo tudo que já fechei), mas a pergunta estará aberta.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento "*se a pergunta voltar a ser reaberta o lock permanece*" - nesse caso, a mensagem do bloqueio poderia ser dinâmica (só diz que são aceitas novas respostas caso a pergunta esteja aberta). Editei a pergunta adicionando essa sugestão

Comment: Eu não discordo, só quis deixar claro que fechamento e lock são coisas distintas e "tecnicamente" (seguindo as dicas) a pessoa poderá ter a pergunta respondida, já que ambos recursos são totalmente independentes, eu só estou usando eles de forma combinada para ajudar mesmo na orientação, era apenas um explicação de que a frase atual do sistema não é totalmente sem sentido e como eu já disse, ótima iniciativa, tornar melhor essa frase seria o ideal.